# Is service management within the scope of the site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Is the subject of IT service management (for example discussion about implementing specific ITIL processes) within the scope of this site? I know, that it is really on the very edge of what Programmers aims to be, but would like to know your opinion nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesonally I think that support should be covered, at least as far as it relates to programmers and programming, my question / concern would be that something like ITIL is far wider ranging than that (or can be) so it will ultimately depend on how you target your question - the more you can keep it specific to programmers the more likely it is to (a) survive and (b) actually get good answers - after all, that's what people here know about.